# ¿Cómo determinar el tamaño en memoria de datos en Haskell?

Tags: programación-funcional, haskell, estructuras-de-datos

Estudiando [Purely Functional Data Strcutures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AKE1V04) de Chris Okasaki; encontre que una estrctura recursiva que regrese todos los sufijos posibles de una lista, ordenadas del sufijo más largo al más corto,

```haskell
suffixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
suffixes (x:xs) = (x:xs) : suffixes xs
suffixes _ = []
```

beberian tener una complejidad de tiempo de O(n) y uso de memoria de O(n)

Hay una tabla en la [Wiki de Haskkel - GHC - Memory Footprint](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Memory_Footprint). Pero esto solo funciona para datos "sencillos" y que no comparten valores internamente.

¿Cómo puedo determinar el tamaño en memoria de `suffixes [1..10]`?

Comment: El uso de memoria, ¿no debería ser O(n^2) (suma de la progresión aritmética de longitudes)?

Comment: No! Lo que hace internamente es crear nuevos apuntadores al punto de la lista en el que tienen que empezar los sufijos (n apuntadores) y es lo unico que regresa. Las pruebas que hice con esta pregunta/respuesta lo demuestran. (Esto es posible gracias a la inmutabilidad de la lista que se pasa como argumento)

Comment: Si quieres aprender más sobre esto te recomiendo el libro que cite; Purely Functional Data Strctures de Chris Okasaki.

Comment: Entiendo que la memoria se limite a `n` apuntadores, pero tampoco es equivalente a la memoria de `n` elementos. Yo ponía `O(n^2)` teniendo en cuenta sólo el algoritmo, sin conocimiento de la estructura interna.

Comment: Lo que yo preguntaba era sobre uso de memoria real; no la longitud de la lista en termino de elementos. C:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay un paquete de cabal en Hackage llamado [ghc-datasize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-datasize); que regresa el espacio en memoria en bytes de estructuras de datos recursiveas. Para usarlo se tiene que instalar

```
cabal update
cabal install ghc-datasize
```

e importar en un archivo junto con la definicion de `suffixes`:

```
import GHC.DataSize
```

y se puede usar en GHCi de la siguiente manera:

```
Prelude> :l suffixes.hs
*Main> let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
*Main> let sa = suffixes a
*Main> recursiveSize a
2704
*Main> recursiveSize sa
4704
*Main> let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
*Main> let sa = suffixes a
*Main> recursiveSize a
4920
*Main> recursiveSize sa
6920
```

Comment: `ghc-datasize` da una idea del tamaño real, pero no del previsto algoritmicamente. El compilador hace bien su papel y no desperdicia memoria si puede evitarlo. Por ejemplo: `let a = [1..]` ó `let a = repeat 1` son listas infinitas con tamaños finitos, y `suffices a` también tiene tamaño finito. Es una evidencia de que la estrutura de datos se guarda algebraicamente.

Comment: Sí, de hecho era lo que queria checar; que es lo que esta explicando Okasaki en el Capitulo 2 del libro Purely Functional Data Structures

Comment: Y otra cosa interesante es que si no forzaba a que se mostrar o si no ponia explicitamente la lista era O(1) de complejidad y memoria. Me encanta que Haskell sea flojo pero a veces arruina demostraciones interesantes(No pude escribir let a = [1..10] por ejemplo)

Comment: Ese tipo de demostraciones que buscas es más de lenguajes imperativos. Yo estoy algo harto de afirmar que utilizar datos inmutables no implica necesariamente tener que usar más memoria.

Comment: En este caso ocupo menos memoria y lo estaba checando porque se me hizo interesante; no estoy diciendo que en general imperativo o funcional use más memoria.

Answer (score 3):

Según la pregunta y los comentarios a tu autorespuesta, lo que te interesa no es el tamaño actual en la memoria, sino al contrario la **complejidad asintótica del uso de memoria** ("asymptotic memory complexity") de los algoritmos en Haskell.

Pero cuando enfocamos la pregunta hacia ese tema, Los hechso más importante que cabe recalcar son que:

1. Haskell es un idioma en el cual la **evaluación vaga** ("lazy evaluation") es una técnica común;
2. Por lo tanto, el costo de evaluación de una expresión depende no sólo de su contenido, sino también del contexto en el cual aparece;
3. Así que, en conclusión, **la pregunta no tiene una respuesta única**.

Trabajemos ahora algunos ejemplos.

---

Un ejemplo bastante dramático es la siguiente función:

```
ejemplo1 xs = 5 + const 7 (suffixes xs)
```

`const` tiene esta definición:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const a _ = a
```

Bajo una estrategia de evaluación vaga, cuando evaluamos cualquier aplicación de `const` descartamos su segundo argumento sin evaluarlo.  Lo cual quiere decir que la complejidad de memoria del segundo argumento no contribuye nada a la de la expresión. Si evaluamos a mano nuestro ejemplo obtenemos que:

```
ejemplo1 [1..]
  = 5 + const 7 (suffixes [1..])
  = 5 + 7
  = 12
```

Nunca tocamos `suffixes [1..]`.  Así que *en este ejemplo*, ¡su costo de tiempo y de memoria son zero!  Lo cual califica cómo complejidad de O(1) en ambos casos.

---

Miremos otro ejemplo:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

ejemplo2 xs = length (suffixes xs)

-- Definición de `length`:
length :: [a] -> Int
length = aux 0
  where 
    -- El punto de exclamación es un "bang pattern", que
    -- causa que el argumento `n` se evalúe estrictamente
    -- (sin evaluación vaga)
    aux !n [] = n
    aux !n (_:xs) = aux (n+1) xs
```

Ahora evaluemos:

```
ejemplo2 [1..5]
  = length (suffixes [1..5)
  = aux 0 (suffixes [1..5)
  = aux 0 ([1..5] : suffixes [2..5])
  = aux 0 ([1..5] : suffixes [2..5])
  = aux 1 (suffixes [2..5])
  = aux 1 ([2..5] : suffixes [3..5])
  = aux 2 (suffixes [3..5])
  ...
  = aux 5 (suffixes [])
  = aux 5 []
  = 5
```

Una técnica sencilla y útil para estimar la complejidad de un algoritmo en Haskell es evaluar ejemplos a mano, como hice aquí, y observar como varían los dos siguientes factores cuando cambiamos el tamaño o valor de los argumentos:

1. El número de pasos que se require para llegar a la respuesta;
2. El tamaño de la expresión mas grande en el proceso de evaluación.

En este ejemplo lo que podemos notar es que:

1. El largo del cómputo resultado de `ejemplo2` es proporcional al largo de la lista que le pasamos como argumento.  Así que `ejemplo2` tiene una complejidad de tiempo de O(n), donde `n` es el largo de la lista.
2. El tamaño de la expresión en el paso más largo es constante.  Por lo tanto, `ejemplo2` tiene uso de memoria de O(1).

Esta técnica de evaluación a mano tiene sus dificultades, sin embargo:

- Hay que aprender a evaluar las expresiones a mano en el órden correcto, que refleja correctamente la evaluación vaga;
- Se torna un poco difícil estimar la complejidad de memoria cuando hay *subexpresiones compartidas*.  Por ejemplo, en la función `square x = x * x`, la subexpresión `x` aparece dos veces y si no tomamos cuidado podríamos calcular la complejidad de memoria erróneamente.

---

Los ejemplos se pueden multiplicar, pero con estos basta para ilustrar la dificultad de la pregunta.